# React router open modal

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, redux-router

I'm new to react and redux world. I have a question regarding react router. Following is my App component.

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/callback" component={CallbackPage} />
          <Route exact path="/list" component={List} />
          <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

My list class looks like this:

```
export class List extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
    };

    this.depositHandleToggle = this.depositHandleToggle.bind(this);
  }
  depositHandleToggle = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(push(`${this.props.match.url}/deposit`));
  }
  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
      <Route path={`${match.url}/deposit`} component={Modal} />
        <button onClick={this.depositHandleToggle}>Open Modal</button>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default List;
```

So my question is: when i click the button in List container, why my router can't find this url 'localhost:xxx/list/deposit'? it renders the App component but it never goes back to List component. Is it possible to have the custom routes inside my list container? Am i doing something wrong? Please someone help me with this.

I hope you understand my question. Thanks in advance.

**ANSWER:**

I found the answer, the issue was in my App component list route. I was having the *'exact'* keyword, that's why route inside my list component was not working. Following way is the correct way.

```
<Route path="/list" component={List} />
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/callback" component={CallbackPage} />
          <Route exact path="/list" component={List} />
          <Route exact path="/list/deposit" component={Modal} />
          <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

export class List extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
      <Link to={'/deposit'}>Open Modal</Link> 
    );
  }
}
export default List;
```

in that component you should handle modal open close.

Comment: can you give ma an example pls?

Comment: see the example

Comment: i'll check this out

Comment: still the url is 'localhost:xxx/list', but i want it to be 'localhost:xxx/list/deposit'. and it doesn't trigger Modal component render method?

Comment: it's a normal component with some text inside div. similar to list component but no routes

Comment: i mean you should define it in app component, line other components and routes.

Comment: i have difine it in List component. Do i have to define it in App component as well?

Comment: <Route path={`${match.url}/deposit`} component={Modal} />... modal is the deposit component

Comment: thanks @jsDevia, i want it to have localhost:xxx/list/deposit url. how can i do that?

Comment: could i do that in List component? like what i did in my example? or do i have to do that in my App component?

Comment: you should define your routes in one single file. This comes from my three year experience in react.
But i think you need another solution, based on your question my answer is good enough for u, but i think your situation needs another answer.

Comment: yes. if u have more questions about react , redux , saga and all things about react I would be happy to help u.